# Graphics glitch after unlock from lock screen

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-driver

Anyone having Graphics glitch after unlocking from lock screen? This issue started just since last two days only, If I restart PC everything works perfectly until I lock the screen. I know this is probably related to Nvidia but anyone having a similar issue? I'm using GTX 1050ti
[image]

At first I thought this may be related to chrome but this happens across all applications.

Thank you,

Comment: Which drivers do you have installed? Anything in your error logs? Was there an update a couple of days ago when this began? If so, what updated?

Comment: i have a similar problem, when i lock/unlock it take some seconds all black and sometimes my browser or text editor glitch like yours, this is my second laptop with this problem, both with nvidia cards, i love elementary os, but this problem is annoying